# O365 Management Activity API: Webhook Notifications not being received

Tags: office-365, webhooks

I've been playing around with the Management Activity API in Office 365 as outlined in the [api documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-au/office/office-365-management-api/office-365-management-activity-api-reference).

Everything is working as expected, except that when I add a subscription with a notification webhook, the webhook is never called.

I set up the webhook as an Azure function, and when registering the subscription, the validation call is made to the function as expected, and I can confirm that new content is available in the management api as calls to the subscriptions/content endpoint are successful.

A call to the /subscriptions/list endpoint confirms my webhooks are registered and enabled, but a call to /subscriptions/notifications always returns an empty array.

My tenant is a Developer tenant, not sure if that makes a difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A week or so after I posted this the notifications started to come through, so not sure what the initial problem was.

I did find, however, that notifications were not very frequent. This may be due to my dev tenant having relatively low activity, so I ended up with a solution that polls the api at regular intervals instead of relying on the webhook notifications.